# Any reconstructions of earliest mentioned classification of canon?

Tags: history

> Monks, there is the case where some worthless men study the Dhamma:
>   dialogues, narratives of mixed prose and verse, explanations, verses,
>   spontaneous exclamations, quotations, birth stories, amazing events,
>   question & answer sessions [the earliest classifications of the Buddha's teachings]. [MN22](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.022.than.html)

It's probably a hazy endeavour, but has anyone attempted to reconstruct such a classification from either the suttas or agamas?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a dodgy quote (despite coming from the exalted MN 22) because birth stories appear to be later additions?

This said, I did try to compile 'birth stories' and only found around a dozen in the Buddhavaca suttas, such as AN 3.15; MN 50; MN 81; MN 123; MN 143; etc; which seem to be in the style of later works, such as the Jataka Tales, Buddhavamsa & Apadana.

The *lokuttara* dhamma in SN 22.79 says all memories of the past are mere aggregates & not-self.